# Running multiple fixtures in parallel in R# 7.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit, resharper

Any way of running multiple text fixtures *within the same assembly* in parallel with R# 7.0?

I have an assembly with a lot of DB-bound tests that runs slower than all other test assemblies, but I'm quite reluctant to break it up as it would result in quite a few new projects.

Cheers!

Comment: You can make several unit test sessions, each containing part of your test set. You would need to invoke test run for each session manually (press Run on each tab), but then tests in different test session would run in parallel. If that is acceptable for you, then I can describe in details.

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy, I'm trying to save time, so anything that doesn't involve user interaction would be preferrable, but good idea nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now, there is no built-in ReSharper functionality to run multiple text fixtures within the same assembly in parallel. This is planned for future versions, but as of 7.0 it is not implemented.

I suggest making several unit test sessions, each containing part of your test set. You can create new sessions via ReSharper->Unit tests->Create new session (Ctrl-U-N) and then add different tests to them. You would need to invoke test run for each session manually (press Run on each tab), but then tests in different test session would run in parallel.

And the last point. If your tests take so much time, then I suggest to run them on servers using continuous integration tools such as TeamCity or CruiseControl.NET. You just commit your changes and tests run automatically for them, while you are happily coding further.